# php exif; latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, exif

Im trying to get latitude and longitude from an image. The exif gps array:

```
   [GPS] => Array
    (
        [GPSVersion] => 
        [GPSLatitudeRef] => N
        [GPSLatitude] => Array
            (
                [0] => 57/1
                [1] => 42/1
                [2] => 45594/1000
            )

        [GPSLongitudeRef] => E
        [GPSLongitude] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11/1
                [1] => 54/1
                [2] => 56615/1000
            )

        [GPSAltitudeRef] => 
        [GPSAltitude] => 228/10
        [GPSTimeStamp] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10/1
                [1] => 46/1
                [2] => 12000/1000
            )

        [GPSStatus] => A
        [GPSMeasureMode] => 3
        [GPSSpeedRef] => K
        [GPSSpeed] => 4/10
        [GPSTrackRef] => T
        [GPSTrack] => 1719/100
        [GPSImgDirectionRef] => M
        [GPSImgDirection] => 32900/100
        [GPSMapDatum] => WGS-84
        [GPSDateStamp] => 2011:04:23
        [GPSDifferential] => 0
    )
```

I thought latitude would be 45594/1000 and longitude 56615/1000, but those values seems to be way of. Am i doing it wrong, or is the data incorrect? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd interpret:

`[GPSLatitudeRef] => N
[GPSLatitude] => Array
            (
                [0] => 57/1
                [1] => 42/1
                [2] => 45594/1000
            )`

As 57 degrees, 42 minutes, 45 seconds, and 594 milliseconds North... Ergo: somewhere up in Canada or Siberia.

The next question is "What's the datum?", which is given in the `[GPSMapDatum] => WGS-84` element.

Cheers. Keith.

PS: Google(WGS-84) says: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System

PPS: Looking at http://www.worldpress.org/images/maps/europe_600w.jpg, I'd put that point in the North Sea close to the coast of Norway... Am I warm?

Comment: The /# parts of each coordinate component could be the maximum error range. So 57 +/- 1 degree north. rather huge.

Comment: Yeah Marc, I hadn't thought of that; that'd be a neat expression of accuracy. I ignored the "/1"s because I didn't understand them at all ;-)